# How to check same value from result of query and catch first value, in golang

Tags: go

Please help me, how to check same value from query 
and just catch first value in golang or python

{
    "data":[
    "1234567001",
    "1234567001",
    "1234567001",
    "1234567001",
    "4567898001",
    "4567898001",
    "4567898001"
    ]
  }

how to get 2 different values from the data, using go lang

```
vals := []interface{}{}
for _, row := range result {
    nobil := row.Nobilling
    vals = append(vals, nobil)

    if nobil == row.billing {
        continue
    }

    i++
}
```

I just want to store different values ​​from the array

Comment: Could you be more specific? It is not clear what do you want to achieve.
And please provide your code.

Comment: I've edited it, please help

Comment: Best advice: Take the Tour of Go, maybe once more if you completed it already. Note that SO is not a code writing/debugging service; you might better of asking such stuff elsewhere, maybe reddit or golang-nuts.

Comment: Do review your question. its almost impossible to understand what you are saying.

Comment: Pick a language. Do you want an answer for Go, or one for Python?

Comment: for Go language

Comment: Hey, I just realized, you know that "throw away" value (_) in your range, that is an index value for the array so you don't need the `i++`.  I added it to my answer below for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for reflection in go... I say "think" because the way you worded the question is confusing. Something like this?

```
res := []interface{}{
    1,
    "row2",
    struct { str string } { str: "what the heck???" },
}
// one way of reflecting
for i, v := range res {
    if r, ok := v.(int); ok {
        fmt.Printf("%d: You have an int: %d\n", i, r)
    } else if r, ok := v.(string); ok {
        fmt.Printf("%d: You have a string: %q\n", i, r)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%d: Have no idea what this type is: %T\n", i, v)
    }
}
// a cleaner way of reflecting (in my opinion)
for i, v := range res {
    switch r := v.(type) {
    case int:
        fmt.Printf("%d: You have an int: %d\n", i, r)
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%d: You have a string: %q\n", i, r)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%d: Have no idea what this type is: %T\n", i, v)
    }
}
```

Check it in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ca7umhCBXt3

or here in the "Tour of Go": https://tour.golang.org/methods/16